# Date compare has different digits

Tags: python, pandas, compare

**DF**

```
date1            date2
0   201101       201201
1   20150215     2011
2   2019         201907
3   201608       20130706
4   20170717     2018
```

As you see, the date has different logits , 4(20xx), 6(20xxxx), 8(20xxxxxx).
I want to compare these 2 columns, and leave only if the date in 'date1' is earlier.

Output what I want

```
    date1   date2
0   201101  201201
1   2019    201907
2   20170717    2018
```

***condition***

1. If the date can not compare like `2019 - 201907`, don`t know which date is faster, 
   Just leave it.

Thank you for reading

**Edit**

Here is my real dataset

```
    event    start
0   2013    201109
1   20040624    200401
2   20040624    200401
3   2013    20100806
4   20081103    200809
... ... ...
178382  20131029    20130918
178383  20140310    20140125
178384  20140310    20140125
178385  20130410    20131204
178386  20140709    20140227
```

Comment: I think we're missing some information here. Those look like strings, why not parse them to a date type?

Comment: @AMC Do you mean data type? It`s both int64

Comment: Why are they ints? Where is this data coming from?

Comment: @AMC That dataframe just example. So I made it. Int64 from in my real data column, shape is same as example.

Comment: What does your actual data look like, then?

Comment: then..? I  don't understand what's  your saying..

Comment: _That dataframe just example_ I’m asking if we can see the actual DataFrame.

Comment: @AMC I edited. Is it right that you want? ,, It`s just same as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create for each format separate DataFrames filled by dates ot missing values if no match and combine together by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
f1 = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y', errors='coerce')
f2 = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m', errors='coerce')
f3 = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
df1 = df[['date1','date2']].apply(f1)
df2 = df[['date1','date2']].apply(f2)
df3 = df[['date1','date2']].apply(f3)

df4 = df1.fillna(df2).fillna(df3)
print (df4)
       date1      date2
0 2011-01-01 2012-01-01
1 2015-02-15 2011-01-01
2 2019-01-01 2019-07-01
3 2016-08-01 2013-07-06
4 2017-07-17 2018-01-01

df = df[df4['date1'].lt(df4['date2'])]
print (df)
      date1   date2
0    201101  201201
2      2019  201907
4  20170717    2018
```

Comment: Perfect. Always, Thank you!